# Lotus notes external email address auto complete cache

Tags: lotus-notes

Does anyone know know how to get back the external email address auto-complete cache in Lotus notes 8.5.3

Regards
Sas.

Answer (score 2):

Stored in your names.nsf on your local machine. It will rebuild this list as you use the emails or read emails with those addresses.

It is in the "Recent Contacts" view of the names.nsf.

If you have lost it, you should restore from an earlier backup of your personal NAB for speed purposes (remember to upgrade database design when you do).

Answer (score -1):

rename the cache.ndk... it will be work.

Comment: Where do you find this file? Why will renaming it fix the problem? Are there any downsides to doing this? You should [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1061049/edit) your answer to be more complete.